# Why gradle is not loading transitive dependencies of one of the dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, pom.xml

## Updated Question

gradle is loading my project's dependency guice-3.0.jar, but guice's dependencies are NOT being loaded by gradle.

guice-3.0.jar > META-INF > DEPENDENCIES (file) has the following content:

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// Transitive dependencies of this project determined from the
// maven pom organized by organization.
// ------------------------------------------------------------------

Google Guice - Core Library


From: 'an unknown organization'
  - AOP alliance (http://aopalliance.sourceforge.net) aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0
    License: Public Domain 
  - javax.inject (http://code.google.com/p/atinject/) javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1
    License: The Apache Software License, Version 2.0  (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt)
  - CGLIB (http://sourceforge.net/projects/cglib/) org.sonatype.sisu.inject:cglib:jar:2.2.1-v20090111
    License: The Apache Software License, Version 2.0  (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt)

From: 'ObjectWeb' (http://www.objectweb.org/)
  - ASM Core (http://asm.objectweb.org/asm/) asm:asm:jar:3.1
```

gradle seems to be failing in loading javax.inject. So, I get the error mentioned below.

### Work-around

I added guice's dependencies direct into build.gradle of my project.

```
compile group: 'aopalliance', name: 'aopalliance', version: 1.0
compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: 1
compile group: 'org.sonatype.sisu.inject', name: 'cglib', version: '2.2.1-v20090111'
compile group: 'asm', name: 'asm', version: 3.1
```

### Questions

1. It works as a hack, but any genuine fixes are required.
2. Looking at other jars required by my project, they have dependencies defined in META-INF > maven > lib-name-folder-hierarchy > pom.xml, but this guice-3.0.jar has dependencies defined in META-INF > DEPENDENCIES file. Can this different convention cause any issues?

---

## Original Question

For one of my java projects, I performed `gradlew --refresh-dependencies`, and the project build `compileJava` task started throwing the following error:

```
:myproject:compileJava
/<path-to-my-project/MyProvider.java:24: error: cannot access Provider
public class MyProvider<T> implements Provider<T> {
       ^
  class file for javax.inject.Provider not found
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_181). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitTypeParameter(Attr.java:4016)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCTypeParameter.accept(JCTree.java:2224)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:576)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStat(Attr.java:645)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStats(Attr.java:661)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClassBody(Attr.java:4296)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClass(Attr.java:4272)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClass(Attr.java:4201)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attrib(Attr.java:4176)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.attribute(JavaCompiler.java:1248)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile2(JavaCompiler.java:901)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:860)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:33)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:104)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:38)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:163)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:145)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:93)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:245)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:232)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
:myproject:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':myproject:compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.14.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2016-07-18 06:38:37 UTC
Revision:     d9e2113d9fb05a5caabba61798bdb8dfdca83719

Groovy:       2.4.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_181 (Oracle Corporation 25.181-b13)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64
```

It's openJDK.

Well, my team-mates, who haven't performed `gradlew --refresh-dependencies` are facing no such issues. I don't think it's java compiler issue, but it seems to be gradle issue.

When I check using eclipse, the MyProvider.java refers to com.google.inject.Provider from guice-3.0.jar.

com.google.inject.Provider refers to javax.inject.Provider, and that seems to be not included in the dependencies.

1. Any solutions to resovle the issue?
2. Any ways to rollback the refresh-dependencies command?
3. Any work-arounds?

I performed cleanEclipse, eclipse, upgraded gradle to 3.5, and then downgraded to 2.14.1, but no luck.

The similar issue was reported to java but it was closed as Cannot Reproduce: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8222198 .

Comment: Have you tried adding `javax.inject:javax.inject:1` to the dependencies?

Comment: @BjørnVester , yes, adding those dependencies directly into my project works, but I guess, gradle should take care of that. I've updated my question to ask how to force gradle to take care of dependencies of dependencies.

Comment: This seems to be this issue: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1487

Comment: I've filed issue to gradle: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/12644

Comment: The metadata files in META-INF like `dependencies` and `pom.xml` are not used for dependency resolution by Gradle. I don't even think Maven uses the embedded ones. Rather, there should be a pom file next to the jar file in the repository. I've seen a few organisations having their own Maven repository where they manually upload libraries, but in a way that destroys the original pom file and thereby the required transitive dependencies. Maybe you can check if this is the case for you?

Comment: @BjørnVester, Yes, we do have our own Maven repository. The guice jar was referred from the location: ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.inject/guice/3.0/9d84f15fe35e2c716a02979fb62f50a29f38aefa/guice-3.0.jar. I looked into the current POM file at location: ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.inject/guice/3.0/5a106815122ba3584f77006351bfad65f302bcc/guice-3.0.pom. It does NOT contain any tag/info about dependencies. Whereas the earlier guice-3.0.pom did contain tags/info about dependencies. Is that the issue?

Comment: Yes, that looks like the problem. If you can find the dependency on your company's repository, the pom file will probably be empty there, which would be a mistake. The best solution is to fix the pom file on the repository and then run the build with `--refresh-dependencies`. If that is not possible, and if allowed by your company policies, you could configure the dependency to be loaded from Maven Central or JCenter instead. And if that is not possible either, I don't think you have any other choice but to fix the problem in each consuming project like you already did...

Comment: @BjørnVester, That was the issue indeed. We disabled that source which was providing incorrect POM files, then correct POM files were downloaded from jcenter. Then the build ran successfully. Thank you! :)